# Update newView to switch between xml row layouts

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a custom adapter on my listview which is linked to two separate xml layouts in newView and when the activity starts it chooses which layout to use by using a switch. Everything works fine but how do I update newView after the activity has started so i can switch between two different row layouts? Some rows change as I scroll but i would like it to change on my checkedChangeListener.

setOnCheckedChangeListener:

```
auto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.Auto:
            if(toggle.isChecked()){
                seek.setEnabled(true);
            }                   
            toggle.setEnabled(true);
            v=0;
            result.setEnabled(true); break;
        case R.id.Manual:
            seek.setEnabled(false);
            toggle.setEnabled(false);
            v=1;
            result.setEnabled(false); break;
        }
        final MyContactsAdapter adapter = ((MyContactsAdapter)b_list.getAdapter());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
});
```

newView:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    switch(v){
    case 0:
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.blanket_auto, parent, false);break;

    case 1:
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.blanket_manual, parent, false);break;

    }
    return view;
}
```

Thankyou